# Salesforce unmanaged package migration

Tags: salesforce, force.com

My new client has an unmanaged package in their production org. I have access to the package / source code, but I can't modify this instance of the code. I need to move a copy of the package into my development org.  I'm attempting to use the Force.com IDE to deploy the package, but I'm getting a series of errors such as the ones below.

I'm new to Salesforce development. Any help would be appreciated

---

*** Deployment Log ***
Result: FAILED
Date: August 17, 2014 9:52:04 AM EDT

## Deployed From:

Project name: xxx
   Username: xxx
   Endpoint: www.salesforce.com

## Deployed To:

Username: xxx
   Endpoint: www.salesforce.com

## Deploy Results:

File Name:    classes/CreateNewVoucherController.cls
   Full Name:  CreateNewVoucherController
   Action:  NO ACTION
   Result:  FAILED
   Problem: sObject type 'Kumo_Vouchers_Group__c' is not supported. If you are attempting to use a custom object, be sure to append the '__c' after the entity name. Please reference your WSDL or the describe call for the appropriate names.

File Name:    classes/GatewayAuthorizeNet.cls
   Full Name:  GatewayAuthorizeNet
   Action:  NO ACTION
   Result:  FAILED
   Problem: Invalid type: GatewayBase

File Name:    classes/GatewayBase.cls
   Full Name:  GatewayBase
   Action:  NO ACTION
   Result:  FAILED
   Problem: sObject type 'Order__c' is not supported. If you are attempting to use a custom object, be sure to append the '__c' after the entity name. Please reference your WSDL or the describe call for the appropriate names.

Answer (score 1):

based on provided error description I can assume that you tried to deploy a code,  but missed to deploy a sObjects from package.

Try to deploy in a few steps:

1. deploy all sObjects (each object might has an dependency to another object, thus you have to deploy objects without dependencies). Also objects might have dependencies on VF pages which can't be deployed without apex, which in its turn can't be deployed without object. Thus you can comment out a part of sObjects with relates to VF page and uncomment after VF-page deployment.
2. deploy all layouts, object translation, custom labels, applications, static resources, workflow rules
3. deploy apex code
4. deploy apex triggers & VF pages
5. deploy all other components.